# Почему в Java может быть больше 1 метода main в програме?

Tags: java, методы, main

Несколько классов и в каждом или в нескольких методов main. Какой будет выполняться первым и какой далее и т. д.?

Comment: Никакой. Выполняется тот, который явно задан точкой входа в манифесте jar-файла или в командной строке, никакой магии с "вызвать первый main" не существует, как и ограничения на количество таких методов

Comment: Это всегда метод с аргументом string[] args?

Comment: да http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4

Answer (score 3):

Выполняться будет только один, и только тот, который будет явно указан при запуске.

Например, есть два класса:

**TestClass1.java**

```
public class TestClass1{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        // 
    }
}
```

**TestClass2.java**

```
public class TestClass2 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        // 
    }
}
```

При компиляции будет создано два файла `TestClass1.class` и `TestClass2.class` (если будет два public класса в одном файле - компилятор выдаст ошибку `error: class TestClass2 is public, should be declared in a file named TestClass2.java`). А так как у нас будет создано два класса, то выполняться будет первым и единственным только тот `main`, который будет явно указан при старте:

Выполнение первого - `java TestClass1`

Выполнение второго - `java TestClass2`

В случае если у нас все упаковано в .jar файл, то там все равно должен быть указан `Main-Class`, метод `main` которого и будет запускаться

Comment: А что если в одном файле один класс public, а другой - нет, и в обоих классах есть метод main?

Comment: Тот класс который будет указан при запуске, т.е. если у нас будет два класса в одном файле, скомпилируется это все в два файла все равно